# CFClient Error invoking CFC http://domain/cfc/users.cfc: Not found

Tags: coldfusion, phonegap, cfc, cfclient

Good Day all.

I have wriiten a cfclient app. The app was working perfectly until almost a year ago. then with Adobe phonegap removeing support for cli 3xxx

Then the app stoped working.

On the server the app works perfectly but when i try build and run the app on android i get gthe following error.

Error invoking CFC http://fqadmin.atstech.co.za/cfc/users.cfc: Not found [Enable debugging by adding 'cfdebug' to your url paramaters to see more information]

Now the CFC is there going to http://fqadmin.atstech.co.za/cfc/users.cfc?method=getUsersList

I get the users list in JSON format -> the above is for test purpose only.

So i know the server cfc is not only there, but it is working with no errors.

Please find attached zip file of source code / including the server CFC,

Also please see screen shots of the setting on my cfbuilder project.

Latest Build from phonegap - You can see error using apk below

http://fqadmin.atstech.co.za/apptemp/ATS-FQ_3321208.apk

CFbuilder Application

http://fqadmin.atstech.co.za/apptemp/ATS-FQ.zip

Server Side CFC Folder

http://fqadmin.atstech.co.za/apptemp/cfc.zip

Please see below screenshots of settings. Please let me know what im doing wrong.

PLEASE Help

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]